# X-Frame-Options to SAMEORIGIN in Geoserver prevents my iframe to be viewed

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers, geoserver, x-frame-options

```html
exec "$_RUNJAVA" $JAVA_OPTS $MARLIN_ENABLER -DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR="$GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR" -Dgeoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy=false -Djava.awt.headless=true -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=geoserver -jar start.jar
```

I'm developing a map application using Geoserver to host my layers and data. One of my goals is that when a point in the map was clicked, an iframe appears showing some information about the same point. When I realize it on my application the iframe is blocked, X-Frame-Options to SAMEORIGIN is the error. DId someone know how can I avoid it?

The Geoserver documentation has the solution, but the way I applied it had no effect on the application. https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/config.html

This is my exec line in start.sh that should set policy to false.

Comment: duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267758/setting-geoserver-x-frame-options

Comment: But it has not been fixed yet :/

Comment: actually it is working as designed,turning X-Frame off is bad

Comment: It prevents from clickjacking. But I really need to show some information when a point in my map it's clicked :/

Comment: what **exactly** did you try?

Comment: I tried to make a WFS layer, but many problems were appearing, so I go to the geoserver and the layer view had exactly what I needed, when I clicked at one point, the information was projected into an iframe. This is what I am trying to do in my application. I am following the geoserver documentation, and there is the solution, in the link I posted but it does not work for me, the error continues

Comment: what **exactly** did you type into the command line or web xml file to turn XFrame off

Comment: I've tried everything from this post, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267758/setting-geoserver-x-frame-options, exactly the same things. Same with the documentation. All what I've tried was in the web.xml file

Comment: so try setting the variable with -Dgeoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy=false in start up?

Comment: Where did I need to go to set it false? I'm new in map developing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy to fix by following the suggestions in the [GeoServer docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/config.html#x-frame-options-policy).

You need to set either the `geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy` variable to false to turn off X-Frame denial or `geoserver.xframe.policy` to "ALLOW-FROM [uri]"  where uri is the location of your iFrame.

1. add it to the web.xml file:

   <context-param>
        <param-name>geoserver.xframe.policy</param-name>
        <param-value>ALLOW-FROM http://example.com </param-value>
    </context-param>
2. add it to the CATALINA_OPTS or exec line in `startup.sh` or `startup.bat` using the -D form.

   -Dgeoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy=false
3. add it as a system variable (for the user running tomcat or jetty).

   export geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy=false 
   set geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy=false

You can then easily test this is working by running a simple curl request:

First with non of the above:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /geoserver/web HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=F844AFA320C4F711807759A2BEC96625.route1; Path=/geoserver; HttpOnly
< Location: /geoserver/web/;jsessionid=F844AFA320C4F711807759A2BEC96625.route1
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Tue, 29 Jan 2019 11:15:49 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Then with the policy set:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8085/geoserver/web
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8085 (#0)
> GET /geoserver/web HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8085
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM http://example.com
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=node010koqik22omjt1b1wbqewjrmcl0.node0;Path=/geoserver
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Location: http://localhost:8085/geoserver/web/;jsessionid=node010koqik22omjt1b1wbqewjrmcl0.node0
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Jetty(9.4.12.v20180830)
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

and finally with the XFrame turned off:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8085/geoserver/web
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8085 (#0)
> GET /geoserver/web HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8085
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=node01pdyu4npf3xt6130w8gehjai7t0.node0;Path=/geoserver
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Location: http://localhost:8085/geoserver/web/;jsessionid=node01pdyu4npf3xt6130w8gehjai7t0.node0
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Jetty(9.4.12.v20180830)
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: How can I do the 2 and 3 steps writed above, because, I've done the first one and nothing happened, using the curl to check it, the X-Frame-Options still SAMEORIGIN

Comment: please edit your question with the **full** line from your startup.sh file

Comment: Why this need to be so difficult? More than algorithms implementation...

I edited it with my start.sh exec line, did you see somenthing wrong?

Comment: did you restart geoserver?

Comment: Every time I tested something new I restarted the geoserver.

Comment: you are on linux? other wise you need to edit start.bat

Comment: Yeah I'm using Linux, doesn't matter what I do, the X-Frame-Options still the same (SAMEORIGIN)

Comment: Iam I have no words to thank you but THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I'm doing something wrong so I downloaded geoserver again, followed your steps and finally it works! Thank you too much my friend!